# Why is my Flask Web App not Detecting Changes in Code

Tags: python, html, flask

My Flask Web App doesn't change when I change my html code for website templates. I have set the environment variable `FLASK_DEBUG` to 1.

This is part of my Python code for application.py:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, redirect
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True
```

Comment: Where is your `main`? Where do you run the application?

Comment: Could you create Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? Is flask session or sqlalchemy needed in example? How do you run you application? Could you be more specific what "doesn't change" if you edit your html template?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of clarity to my question but I figured out what was wrong. I had been editing files that were not in my templates folder rather than the ones that correctly were and so these changes were not being detected by the flask app